# Reference request: number-theory-free proof that maximal stabilizer groups determine unique states

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing

### Context.

I am writing on topics such as the [Gottesman-Knill theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottesman%E2%80%93Knill_theorem), using Pauli stabilizer groups, but in the case of *d*-dimensional qudits — where *d* may have more than one prime factor. (I emphasize this because the vast majority of literature on stabilizer formalism in "higher dimensions" involves the cases of *d* prime or *d* a prime power, and makes use of finite fields; I'm considering instead the cyclic groups ℤ<sub>*d*</sub> .)

For any dimension, I characterize a (Pauli) stabilizer group as *an abelian subgroup of the Pauli group, in which every operator has a +1 eigenspace*.

- I'm writing about a result which is well-known for *d* = 2 (and easily generalized to *d* prime):

  > A stabilizer group stabilizes a unique pure state if and only if it is maximal

  where by maximality, I mean that any extension either lies outside the Pauli group, or is non-abelian, or contains operators without +1 eigenvalues.
- Proofs of such results for *d* prime usually rely on the fact that ℤ<sub>*d*</sub><sup>2n</sup> is a vector space (*i.e.* that ℤ<sub>*d*</sub> is a field): this does not hold for *d* composite. There are two recourses: generalize the existing proofs in a way that is robust to the existence of zero divisiors (*e.g.* using tools such as the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)), or avoid number theory altogether and use ideas such as orthogonality relations of Pauli operators.

### Problem.

I actually do have a concise proof of this result already, essentially using no more than orthogonality relations of Pauli operators. But I suspect that I've seen something like it before, and I would like to refer to the prior art if I can (not to mention see if there are better techniques than the one I used, which while not onerous felt less than perfect).

Certainly Knill's papers [[quant-ph/9608048]](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608048) and [[quant-ph/9608049]](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608049) consider similar subjects and use similar techniques; but I couldn't find the result I was looking for there, or in Gottesman's [[quant-ph/9802007]](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802007). I'm hoping that someone can point me to where such a proof might have been published before.

**Note** — the result I'm considering is not one which relates the *cardinality* of the group to the dimension of the stabilized space (which is nice, but trivial both to prove and to find references to); I'm concerned specifically with showing that any stabilizer group *which cannot be extended* stabilizes a unique state, and vice versa.
A reference to a proof that any maximal stabilizer group has the same cardinality would be fine; but again, it must not rely on *d* being prime or ℤ<sub>*d*</sub><sup>2n</sup> being a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll note that my version of the proof appears in

- NdB. *A linearized stabilizer formalism for systems of finite dimension*.
   [Quantum Information & Computation **13** (pp. 73–115)](http://www.rintonpress.com/journals/qiconline.html#v13n12), 2013.
   [[arXiv:1102.3354v4](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3354v4)]

appearing as *Lemma B.3* (page 38) in the published version, and *Lemma 12* (page 23) in the arXiv preprint; in both cases occuring in Appendix B.

If anyone can point to an reference to a proof which is older than this question, I'll accept and reward the earliest such reference which is provided.